# Como mudar a classe de um componente no Html usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

queria saber como mudar a classe de uma div html no JavaScript

```
  <div id="showmodal" class="modal fade" id="myModal">
```

Quero trocar o nome class = "modal fade" para "modal fade in" no javascript, agradeço a atenção!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selecione o elemento e altere o atributo `className`

```
document.getElementById('showmodal').className = "modal fade";
```

Comment: era exatamente isso :) Obrigado!